# javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: when using Liberty 8.5.5.9 with Apache Commons Email 1.4

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, websphere-liberty

I've a web application which sending mail. To perform sending mail I use library which itself based on [Apache Commons Email 1.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email/1.4). When I've used Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.7 everything worked fine, but after I've upgraded to 8.5.5.9 it stopped to work and throwing an exception: `javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException` the **full stack trace** I posted at the end of the question.

Again, I've tried to run it on both installations of Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.7 and 8.5.5.9, on first one it works fine on second it's broken. I've tried to look what the difference and it looks that Liberty itself has `com.ibm.ws.javax.mail-1.5_1.5.xx.jar` package which interfere with Java  `javax-mail-1.5.2` which used by `commons-email 1.4`, see its [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/commons-email/blob/EMAIL_1_4/pom.xml) here.

After some debugging I've paid attention that:
**Liberty 8.5.5.9** uses `com.ibm.ws.javax.mail-1.5_1.5.12.jar` while **Liberty 8.5.5.7** uses `com.ibm.ws.javax.mail-1.5_1.5.10.jar` possible this is caused to my bug.

So, my question is how can I eliminate the influence of `com.ibm.ws.javax.mail` which comes together with liberty to make it work or is there another workaround?
Also, where can I submit bug report for Liberty Team?

**Update**:
It looks that Liberty has [JavaMail 1.5 feature](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_javaMail-1.5.html) which can be enabled or disabled, I didn't enable it explicitly, it looks that on of my features enabled it implicitly, this is my features list:

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

**Update 2**
I've solved this issue by using this article: [Overriding a provided API with an alternative version](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html)

Just make in your server.xml the following changes:

```
<application id="" name="Scholar" type="ear" location="scholar.ear">
  <classloader delegation="parentLast" />
</application>
```

And now your libraries will receive higher precedence then Liberty's libraries.

*Full stack trace of the exception*:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : relay.******.com:25
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421) ~[commons-email-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448) ~[commons-email-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at my.package.mailer.sendHtmlMail(IBMMail.java:96) ~[classes/:?]
    at my.package.mailer.EmailGateway.sendMail(EmailGateway.java:24) [classes/:?]
    at my.package.mailer.EventMailGateway.eventCreatedNotification(EventMailGateway.java:52) [classes/:?]
    at **********.restful.EventsAPI.saveEvent(EventsAPI.java:99) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:636) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:115) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97) [cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:210) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:381) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) [cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:124) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.common_1.0.12.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:256) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.endpoint.AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.invoke(AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.java:134) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.common_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.handleRequest(IBMRestServlet.java:149) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.doPost(IBMRestServlet.java:107) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:99) [com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.server_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1161) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:928) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.12.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:820) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:742) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:682) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:662) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:719) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:248) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) ~[javax.mail-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411) ~[commons-email-1.4.jar:1.4]
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: If the same configuration worked in 8.5.5.7, then this does look like a bug of some kind.  You can report bugs to IBM via the PMR process (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639), or they monitor this forum and might resolve it that way.  According to the Knowledge Center for the javaMail-1.5 feature (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_javaMail-1.5.html), none of the features you enabled should be enabling javaMail-1.5.

Comment: Related: [Bug 6668 - skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6668) which is fixed in JavaMail 1.5.3 and later.  Try upgrading JavaMail to a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using this article: [Overriding a provided API with an alternative version](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html)

Just make in your server.xml the following changes:

```
<application id="" name="Scholar" type="ear" location="scholar.ear">
  <classloader delegation="parentLast" />
</application>
```

And now your libraries will receive higher precedence then Liberty's libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I hit `javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp` after updating from Liberty 8.5.5.8 to 8.5.5.9. Adding `<feature>javaMail-1.5</feature>` to my server.xml worked for me.