# javax.activation.DataHandler conflicts in Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.9

Tags: websphere, classloader, websphere-liberty, server.xml

So, this is my saga from previous question here: [javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: when using Liberty 8.5.5.9 with Apache Commons Email 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130671/javax-mail-nosuchproviderexception-when-using-liberty-8-5-5-9-with-apache-commo/36131903#36131903)
Where I've had have conflicts between [Apache Commons Email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) and Websphere Liberty Feature [JavaMail 1.5 feature](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_javaMail-1.5.html) which I've solved by defining that App's jars loading first by using `<classloader delegation="parentLast" />`.

Everything worked fine until I've started to implement fileupload, by using jax-rs 2.0 as described in this tutorial [Configuring a resource to receive multipart/form-data parts from an HTML form submission in JAX-RS 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_jaxrs_multipart_formdata_from_html.html)

When my code reaches the following line: 
`stream = dataHandler.getInputStream();` `stream` is type of `InputStream` i.e. I'm trying to do something with `DataHandler` object it throws an exception:

```
[ERROR   ] Error occurred during error handling, give up!
loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ParentLastClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/activation/DataHandler"
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage:116'
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ParentLastClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/activation/DataHandler"
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ParentLastClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/activation/DataHandler"
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ParentLastClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/activation/DataHandler"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:327)
    at [internal classes]
    at ****.EventsAPI.handleUploadedEventForm(EventsAPI.java:174)
    at ****.EventsAPI.postFormData(EventsAPI.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:636)
    ... 1 more
```

And indeed there's `DataHandler` object as part of [Apache Commons Email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) and `DataHandler` in IBM's implementation of `IAttachment` see [javadoc](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.jaxrs20_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/jaxrs20/multipart/IAttachment.html), and they are conflicting.

So, how can it be resolved? Can it be resolved through configuration? Writing custom classloader isn't acceptable solution.

**Update**: It isn't clear from my question but now I have two stages, one when I'm using `<classloader delegation="parentLast" />` my mailing work but fileupload doesn't work and without `<classloader delegation="parentLast" />` my mailing doesn't work but fileuploading work. When I deploy my app on WAS Liberty 8.5.5.7 or 8.5.5.8 it works fine, the problem exists only from 8.5.5.9

Comment: have you tried nesting a `<classloader delegation="parentLast"/>` element in your `<application>` element in your server.xml?  This should ensure that any libs provided by your application take precedence over any conflicting classes in Liberty.

Comment: Yes, I didn't explain myself well (now I've updated my question) but with `<classloader delegation="parentLast" />` mailing working but uploading doesn't and without `<classloader delegation="parentLast" />` uploading working but mailing doesn't. The problem exists only in `8.5.5.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've find workaround to this issue.

First of all I've changed **scope** to `<scope>provided</scope>` of all included dependencies which has my library. Once again, I used my library which to send emails, which depend itself on:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So my parent application was required to supply all required dependencies, `common-emails` and `commons-io`. `commons-io` I've added through the parent's `pom.xml` regarding `commons-email` I've installed feature [javaMail-1.5](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_javamail.html) explicitly which already has this library. Also I've removed:  `<classloader delegation="parentLast" />`

**The only one question remained unanswered why did it conflict before? If anybody will provide more detailed explanation it'll be great.**